# How to generate barcode in ionic 2

Tags: ionic2, barcode

I have a simple question,
It is how to make or convert string to barcode
(Not QRcode), what i've done is convert string to QrCode using ngxQrcode2,

But, how about barcode, do you guys have some references or sample how to do that?

Comment: You can use any angular 2+ component, like https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-barcode

Comment: thanks bro, anyway I have used that plugin, so, how to set the barcode size I using this css  but doesn't works `<ngx-barcode style=" width:220px; margin: auto;height: 150px;" [bc-value]="value" [bc-display-value]="true"></ngx-barcode>`